# OpenGL texture offset issue

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, textures, sdl-2

I'm running into an issue with a texture's rows being offset.  As a test I'm creating a 512x4 texture from/to GL_RGBA.  sizeof(_color) outputs 4.  It should just be a gradient that goes from black to blue on the X.  It looks like it's being read from an offset, as sometimes it ends with corrupted results that last about 1/3rd of a row (width).

If I change the fragment shader to output UV coordinates on the red and green channels, I get UV coordinates that look like they're properly set, such as 0,0 (TL)  1,0 (TR),  0,1 (BL) and 1,1 (BR).  I can't see this being a UV issue anyway.

I'm using SDL2 on OSX, which may be the source of the issue.  The result is good on Linux/SDL2, so I'm utterly clueless as to what state variable could possibly cause this.

[image: OpenGL texture offset]

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char r,g,b,a;
} _color;

glGenTextures(1, &self->id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self->id);

_color* c = (_color*)malloc(sizeof(_color) * 512 * 4);
_color* pc = c;
for( int y = 0; y < 4; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < 512; x++ ) {
        pc->r = 0;
        pc->g = 0;
        pc->b = (u_char)((float)x / (float)512 * 255.0);
        pc->a = 255;
        pc++;
    }

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 512, 4, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void *)c);

printf("glGetError = %d\n", glGetError()); // Outputs no error

free(c);
```

UV mapped to gl_FragColor (red = U, green = V)
[image: UV output]

Texture lookup changed to: texture2D(u_texture, vec2(v_uv.x, 0.0)); (y forced to 0)
[image: V (or UV.y) coordinate set to 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be an alignment issue. Set the proper GL_UNPACK_… parameters with glPixelStore before uploading the texture data.